# how to get state from child component

Tags: react-native

I need to get the state of the number from the component Numberplus
And display in the App component

app component:

```
import React from "react";
import { Text, View } from "react-native";
import Numberplus from "./Number";

function App() {
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>{/* How to get Numberplus component State here */ Number}</Text>
      <Numberplus />
    </View>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Numberplus component:

```
import { Button, Text, View } from "react-native";

function Numberplus() {
  let [Number, setNamber] = useState(0);

  return (
    <View>
      {/*<Text>{Number}</Text>*/}
      <Button
        onPress={() => {
          setNamber(++Number);
        }}
        title="Plus"
      />
    </View>
  );
}

export default Numberplus;
```

[**See more details and display the output result**](https://codesandbox.io/s/restless-feather-pr0gl?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Put your `state` in `parent component` and pass it via props to `child component` or You can use `context api`

Answer (score 2):

You can solve this problem either using redux or holding the state in your parent component. I can not explain whole redux here but here is how you can manage it with state.

App.js

```
import React from "react";
import { Text, View } from "react-native";
import Numberplus from "./Number";

function App() {
  let [Number, setNumber] = useState(0);

  return (
    <View>
      <Text>{/* How to get Numberplus component State here */ Number}</Text>
      <Numberplus number={Number} onPress={() => {
          setNumber(++Number);
        }} />
    </View>
  );
}

export default App;
```

NumberPlus.js

```
import { Button, Text, View } from "react-native";

function Numberplus() {
  return (
    <View>
      {/*<Text>{this.props.number}</Text>*/}
      <Button
        onPress={this.props.onPress}
        title="Plus"
      />
    </View>
  );
}

export default Numberplus;
```